# TFS Online build error: WebApplication.targets" was not found trying to build a VS2008 app

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, msbuild, azure-devops

I just uploaded a sample project to TFS Online (very simple one-form app) and the CI build is failing and giving the following error. I'm running VS2008:

```
Debug | Any CPU
1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
$/Sample VS 2008 Projecr/SampleApp.sln - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
C:\a\src\SampleApp\SampleApp.csproj (77): The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v9.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Other Errors
1 error(s)
Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException) Exception Stack Trace: at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Can anyone help me with this or point me to an existing thread that discusses it? I've seen similar posts re: using a local build server but nothing re: using TFS Online.

Answer (score 2):

[As you can see here](http://listofsoftwareontfshostedbuildserver.azurewebsites.net/), visual studio 2008 is not installed on the Hosted Build Server. You might need to update your 
solution to be compatible with Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 for it to compile successfully on Visual Studio Online. If you do not have the license, you could use [the Express edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-web).

Comment: Thanks - I was kind of assuming that but hoped for a better solution. I'd love to upgrade the solution, but 2008 is what most of our apps are in and there's not much appetite for upgrading right now. Thanks anyway! I'm trying to sell them on TFS and this isn't going to help my situation much :-(

Comment: You could always run an on-premise build server that has Visual Studio 2008 installed. And you could try putting the required.

Comment: .Targets file and task assemblies in source control te see if vso will pick those up for you. You might need to edit each project file to tell msbuild the correct location of this targets file.